# sorting the levels of a factor variable using a if statment

Tags: r, dplyr

Using the below toy data, how can I sort x if y=a, y=b etc. I prefer to use the sample code to do so but I could not involve an if statement. I belive a loop would be really efficient.

#my data

```
dataframe <- data.frame(
  x = c("apple", "orange", "banana", "strawberry"),
  y = c("a", "b", "a", "b"),
)
```

******# my prefered code without if statement******

```
data.frame$x <- factor(
  data.frame$x,
  levels = c(
    "apple", "orange", "banana", "strawberry"),
  labels = c(
    "apple", "banana", "orange", "strawberry")
)
```

Comment: Please double check your code/data before posting, make sure it actually works. Your dataframe creation code doesn't work nor does your attempt. What is `data.frame$x` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `arrange` on a logical vector and then change the `levels`

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe1 <- dataframe %>% 
     arrange(y == 'b', x) %>%
     mutate(x = factor(x, levels = unique(x)))

dataframe1$x
#[1] apple      banana     orange     strawberry
#Levels: apple banana orange strawberry
```

---

If there are more than 2 unique elements in 'y', then the option is to use `factor` on the 'y' with `levels` specified in that order

```
dataframe1 <- dataframe %>%
    arrange(factor(y, levels = c('a', 'b')), x) %>%
    mutate(x = factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
```

#### data

```
dataframe <- structure(list(x = c("apple", "orange", "banana", "strawberry"
), y = c("a", "b", "a", "b")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to include a loop; how can I use your code to go through all levels of y (e.g., y=='b', y=='a', etc.). In my data, y has 20 levels.

Comment: @NaderMehri Can you update your example with a more general case so that I can test

Comment: @NaderMehri can you test my update.  In the full data, you may need to change the `levels` to the actual levels in that order you want

Comment: Great! Thanks. This works perfectly. One more question that I would like to know for my further reference. How can I descendingly sort the x levels? Hope this is just a matter of adding to your valuable solution.

Comment: @NaderMehri You can wrap with `desc` i.e. `dataframe1 <- dataframe %>%
     arrange(desc(factor(y, levels = c('a', 'b'))), x) %>%
    mutate(x = factor(x, levels = unique(x)))`

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but got ascending sort. dataframe1 <- dataframe %>% 
  arrange(desc(y == 'b', x)) %>%
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = unique(x)))

Comment: @NaderMehri I coded it differently.  In your code, you are applying the `desc` on both columns with a single desc,  it would be `desc(y == 'b'), desc(x)`

Comment: This did not work. The data frame remains unchanged!

Comment: @NaderMehri It is changing for me though `dataframe1 <- dataframe %>%
     arrange(desc(factor(y, levels = c('a', 'b'))), desc(x)) %>%
     mutate(x = factor(x, levels = unique(x)));levels(dataframe1$x)#
[1] "strawberry" "orange"     "banana"     "apple"`

Comment: Could you please apply your code for y=='b'? I tried this but it did not work: dataframe1 <- dataframe %>% 
  arrange(desc(y == 'b', desc(x))) %>%
  mutate(x = factor(x, levels = unique(x)))

Comment: @NaderMehri You are missing a `)` after `y== 'b'` i.e. `desc(y == 'b')` i.e. the `)` is at wrong place